# Unable to spawn process on another node in Erlang

Tags: erlang, spawn

When I try to create a new process on separate node using

```
Pid = spawn(mynode, mymodule, myfunction, [self()])
```

(`myfunction/1` is exported), I get this error:

```
Error in process <0.10.0> on node 'no@de1' with exit value:
{undef,[{mymodule, myfunction, [<33.64.0>], []}]}
```

I tried to set `-compile(export_all)` flag, but assuming the additional braces in error log, this is not the case.
I don't know what causes the error and I have no clue what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you get is saying “There is no module ‘mymodule’ and/or no function ‘mymodule:myfunction/1’”.
This means mymodule is not loaded in the code server of your separate node.
To load mymodule's code there you need something like [this snippet](http://erldocs.com/R16B03/kernel/rpc.html?i=1&search=rpc%3amulticall#multicall/5) or [this function](https://bitbucket.org/fenollp/brocessing/src/f6f5d70297d25dcf6245056450ef668aff829799/src/stateless.erl?at=master#cl-102)

Comment: Same answer, different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945899/spawn-remote-process-w-o-common-file-system
Thank you, I wasn't aware of that. Thought Erlang would handle it itself.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check that the module `mymodule` is in the path of no@de1?

When you spwan a process using spawn(mynode, mymodule, myfunction, [self()]), the VM needs to load the code before executing it.

If you use a high order function (a fun) in this way `spawn(Node, Fun)`, then in is not more necessary to have the code in the path (but beware that any call to a function in the function definition need to be solved on the remote node)

Answer (score 0):

go to no@de1 and run `m(mymodule).` It should clarify if the module is loadable and which functions does export.

also: check if the other node is reachable. Do a `net_adm:ping` on it.