# Is it possible to add a local event handler to a remote event manager

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I have an event manager running in its own Erlang node. I would like to use it as a simple event broker and let other applications, on other nodes, subscribe to it by adding their own event handler.

My testing setup looks like this (sorry the terrible indentation)
[image]

When running this I get an error like:

```
{'EXIT',{undef,[{event_handler_a,init,[[]],[]},
                {gen_event,server_add_handler,4,
                           [{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,429}]},
                {gen_event,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,270}]},
                {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                          [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}}
```

So now, I am wondering if I am doing something wrong or if this architecture is just not possible. Since the logic in my event handler is entirely related to my application, I would prefer to keep it within my application release. Having an event handler for each application inside my event manager release is probably going to get messy real quick.

Comment: I don't know much about `gen_event`, but that error looks like `gen_event` tried to call `event_handler_a:init([])` and either that module or that function was not defined/loaded on that Erlang node.

Comment: @Dogbert I forgot about this. If the event manager call the init/1 callback from the event handler, it will need to specify the node name. Unfortunately, the doc shows 
`add_handler(EventMgrRef, Handler, Args) -> Result` with `Handler = Module | {Module,Id}`

Comment: I think you can pass that as `Args`, so `gen_event:add_handler(_, _, node1@host1)`.

Comment: If I understand what is happening correctly (I hope not), my app calls `add_handler/3`, then the event manager calls back `init/1`. If this is the case, in my situation, the callback would have to be done over rpc to work. It would totally ruin the whole idea of having a broker in the first place.

Comment: From [the doc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_event.html#add_handler-3()) _Adds a new event handler to event manager EventMgrRef. The event manager calls Module:init/1 to initiate the event handler and its internal state._ So the event handler module has to be on the same node that the event manager.

Comment: I might be able to use [this trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1946173/3719845) to load my event handler on my remote event manager.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible. `gen_event` works a bit differently from other behaviours, in that the code in your callback module (the one you pass as an argument to `gen_event:add_handler/3`) is run in the *same* process as the event manager.  Therefore, if the event manager is running on a remote node, the event handler will run on that same node.

One way to achieve this is to create an event handler callback module that forwards events to a process on the desired node.  You could then do something like this:

```
gen_event:add_handler({event_manager, node1@host1}, my_event_forwarder, [self()]).
```

Comment: That's what I thought. I might also be able to create a very generic handler that take a `fun()` as its init argument and just pass all the events to this `fun()`. Subscribing would be a matter of always adding the same handler module with different `fun()` to do different things.

Comment: Note that the module that the fun is defined in must be loaded on the node where it is called.